# Can't partly deploy in aws api gw?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am using a Swagger file for creating aws api gateway, so I could connect into my rest api.

(So all the api components are already existing in aws gw).

I have noticed that when I am trying to deploy the api before connecting all the components to a server, the api gw leaves a message of `"No integration defined for method".`
How can I deploy only part of the api, so I won't have to create every component only when it's ready to deploy?

Comment: Deploying an API partially is not possible. What do you mean with 'I wont have to create every component..'

Comment: For example - I have a swagger file with 2 components - "student" and "class". I have finished developing the student part and I want to connect to it, but I haven't developed the class part. How can I deploy the student part only?

Comment: if you have not developed the `class` part then delete the `class` methods or all the methods that you have not fully developed. In the GUI you can click on `delete method`. Then trying deploying again!

Comment: Comment out the class function until its ready, when its ready uncomment it and deploy it...